# How can I insulate an oddly-sized framing cavity with batts?

Tags: insulation

I have a cavity that is an odd 17". Is it OK to just combine parts of a 16" rock wool batt, or should I get a 24" batt and cut it down? None of the other cavities are over 16", so getting a bunch of 24" batts (since these seem to come in pallet quantities), would mean having to butcher a lot more batts than if I got a bunch of 16s.

Thoughts?

Comment: Or this? [Can't friction fit insulation due to oversized space](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91735/cant-friction-fit-insulation)

Comment: The cavity is 17" wide by about 8 feet tall. It's an odd portion of a cantilever sticking out of the house. In fact, the rest of the cavities are a mess between 14" at the widest, down to a 2", due to there being a window and I don't know, other reasons.

Reason for buying by the pallet: Lowe's doesn't seem to want to sell Rockwool R23 batts by less than a pallet of 12. They told me I can return extras. Still annoying. I probably have, in all, roughly 12 feet of insulation to do, so roughly a 100 sq ft (12x8), which 3 bags (4 max if I mess it up really bad) would be sufficien.

Answer (score 5):

Cut the batting into 17" lengths and run multiple pieces up your wall with the orientation sideways rather than the typical up-down. If you need the paper vapor barrier as well, then adjust the width of the batts slightly to give you a staple zone on each side and tape the seams across the 17" opening.

Just make sure there aren't air gaps between the batts, and you should be good. Once in place within the wall cavity and the final wall surface, the friction will hold them in place just fine and they shouldn't shift at all over time.